# How to disable RecyclerView fling but leave scroll working?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fling

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView`. I need to scroll it but to disable fling by swipe gesture.

Originally all work is done at `onTouchEvent` method and I dont know how to disable it without rewriting all touch handling

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `GestureDetector` with a `SimpleOnGestureListener` to capture fling events and decide whether or not to allow them.

```
RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // return true if you want to stop the fling
        // return false if you want to allow the fling
        return true;
    }
});

recycler.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> detector.onTouchEvent(event));
```

[GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onFling()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float))